# DocumentRoot wont change -Ubuntu 20 Apache2 on windows wsl2

Tags: server, apache2, php, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm at my wits end here.
I've installed Ubuntu on windows with wsl2.
I'm trying to setup apache2 to point to /mnt/my/windows/source/code

No matter what I do. DocumentRoot is always /var/www/html
I've tried so much, I think I'm going insane.

This is in my apache2.conf
*tried this out of desperation

```
<Directory /mnt/c/Users/me/Development/online-store/web>
    AllowOverride None
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>


    DocumentRoot /mnt/c/Users/me/Development/online-store/web

    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    ServerName store.test.domain.ca
    ServerAlias store-*.test.domain.ca

    <Directory "/mnt/c/Users/me/Development/online-store/web">
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I disabled the 000 conf file so only this one is enabled.

When I run sudo apache2ctl -S

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   store.test.domain.ca (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/store.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Comment: well i think thats a red herring, all Main roots I look at point there.
Can't get passed it saying cannot write to index.html
No idea why its saying that because I do not have an index.html anywhere and IO have index.php as my index to load

Comment: Does Apache have permission to access that location? Have you checked that AppArmour is not installed and blocking Apache from the non-standard location?

Comment: Never heard of appArmour so no.  I'm currently moving all windows files to Ubuntu so I don't have to point to windows DIR.

Comment: Wen back to the basics.
I changed the document root of 000-default.conf 
to /var/www/mysite
But it still only goes to /var/www/html 

I have no idea whats going on!

Comment: lol apache is creating a index.html file in /var/www dir
My hosts file doesn't point to it...

Comment: everytime i goto store.test it creates a new index.html file
index.html.1 index.html.2  I've never encountered this before

Answer (score 0):

If you've already set up SSL then you may be having the same problem I just had.
[/sites-available/default-ssl.conf] and whichever other SSL relevant documents need to be updated as well. Restart apache service, and immediately pointed to the correct directory.